# How can I apply a condition that check if the integers are equal in the 2nd while loop?

Tags: python

I can't figure out how to execute a condition that check if the user inputs are equal before checking if it is a prime number. My goal is to ask a user to input two prime numbers. And  in the 2nd while loop, I want to make sure that the 2nd number is not equal to the first number in order to be checked if it is a prime number

```
value_P=[]
value_Q=[]

def is_prime(num):
    if num == 2:
        return True
    if num < 2 or num % 2 == 0:
        return False
    for n in range(3, int(num**0.5)+2, 2):
        if num % n == 0:
            return False
    return True

while True:
    try:
        P = int(input("Enter a prime number(P): "))
        if is_prime(P):
            value_P.append(P)
            print("P =", value_P)
            break;
        else:
            print(value_P, "is not a prime number")        
    except ValueError:
        print("Provide an integer value...")
        continue

#2nd while loop
while True:
    try:
        Q = int(input("Enter a prime number(Q). Not the same as the number you entered above: "))
        if is_prime(Q):
            value_Q.append(Q)
            print("Q =", Q)
            break;
        else:
            print(value_Q, "is not a prime number")
    except ValueError:
        print("Provide an integer value...")
        continue
```

Comment: Did you mean: `if P != Q:`?

Comment: Under `if is_prime(Q):` add `if Q == value_P[-1]:`

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the value of Q is inside the P list using an if statement in the 2nd while loop.

```
while True:
    try:
        Q = int(input("Enter a prime number(Q). Not the same as the number you entered above: "))
        if is_prime(Q):
#here the code made sure it's prime, next statement checks if the "Q" input was already previously used as the "P" input. If it is, the loop breaks.
            if Q in value_P:
                 break
            else:
                 value_Q.append(Q)
                 print("Q =", Q)
                 break;
        else:
            print(value_Q, "is not a prime number")
    except ValueError:
        print("Provide an integer value...")
        continue
```